How to convert tikz in eps and include it in same time within a TeX file
For a publication, it is said to me that my .tex-file should " refrain from images generated by LaTeX (i.e., using packages such as pict2e, MetaPost, PSTricks, or tikZ). The images should be submitted in .eps format." Thus, I have to change my tikz-files to eps-files within my tex-file, but how can I do that? I am searching for hours, but I cannot find a solution. As someone, who is still a beginner in LaTeX, I am wondering about how can I be sure that this part of my file became .eps?
I am using XeLaTeX and TeXniccenter. Here is my MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,fit}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, thick, node distance=7em, text width=6em, text centered, minimum height=3.5em}}
\tikzset{container/.style={draw, rectangle, dashed, inner sep=2em}}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}


\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows.blur,arrows.meta,bending,calc,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,chains,positioning} 
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth',
    %Define style for boxes
    punkt/.style={
 %          rectangle,
 %          rounded corners,
  %         draw=black, very thick,
   %        text width=6.5em,
    %       minimum height=2em,
      },
    % Define arrow style
    pil/.style={
           ->,
                    align=left,
      execute at begin node=,
           thin,
           shorten <=2pt,
           shorten >=-4pt,}
}

 

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, text width=10cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=yellow!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=yellow!20,
                   text width=8em},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=yellow!10, text width=6.5em}
}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, shapes, decorations.pathreplacing}



\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=3cm,height=5cm,plotstyle/.style={line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.05:1.01}} 

    
    

\usepackage{polyglossia} %Kommentar 


\setmainlanguage[variant=german, spelling=new, latesthyphen=true]{german}


\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%Für Kapitälchen
\newfontfamily\tgtermes{TeX Gyre Termes}
\makeatletter
  \begingroup
    \tgtermes
    \DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\rmdefault}{m}{sc}{%
      <-> ssub * \f@family/m/sc}{}
    \DeclareFontShape{\f@encoding}{\rmdefault}{bx}{sc}{%
      <-> ssub * \f@family/bx/sc}{}
  \endgroup
\makeatother


\setotherlanguage{syriac}
\newfontfamily\syriacfont[Script=Syriac, Scale=1.3]{Estrangelo Talada}
%\newfontfamily\estrfont[Script=Syriac, Scale=1.3]{Estrangelo Talada Edessa}
\newcommand{\syr}[1]{\RL{\textsyriac{#1}}}
\newcommand{\estr}[1]{\RL{\estrfont{#1}}}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic, Scale=1.3]{Simplified Arabic}

\begin{document}

The result is:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {\Huge $e^{i\pi}=-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}


It should be added...
 
\end{document}


unrelated to your question, but check with your publisher if they allow xelatex and if they allow custom fonts.

I have some problems bringing "standalone" and the packages "tikz-qtree" and "forest" together...

Can you elaborate on the problem you are facing? Maybe post a separate question?

Here is the new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/720650/combination-of-tikz-qtree-and-standalone

Most submission portals usually accept vector images in both EPS and PDF formats. You can use the standalone document class to create your images from tikz code. LaTeX will generate PDF files for your images. You can generate separate PDFs for each of your images. But I usually prefer to put all tikz images in a single file and include specific images using the pdfpages package. So if the submission portal allows me to include the pdfpages package, it becomes more manageable, for me at least.
Contents of image.tex:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% each tikzpicture is placed on a new page

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % on page 1
  \draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
  \draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
  \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{Intersection point};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} % on page 2
  \draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
  \filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle (2pt);
  \draw (-2,-2) .. controls (0,0) .. (2,-2);
  \draw (-2,2) .. controls (-1,0) and (1,0) .. (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Compile the above first to get the image.pdf file and include that in main.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[page=1]{image.pdf}
  \caption{First image}
\end{figure}
% 
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[page=2]{image.pdf}
  \caption{Second image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Thanks! I have some problems with "standalone", because I have made some modifications and I have to use some Oriental languages. How can I put these in the new file?

One possible way is to show the images on separate pages using scrbook or article and turn off the page number (and other artifacts). Now use pdfcrop or a similar tool to crop the pages containing your images.
