Combination of tikz-qtree and standalone
My question is related to this topic: How to convert tikz in eps and include it in same time within a TeX file
Here is my MWE. I do not know why it does not work:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% each tikzpicture is placed on a new page

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=left,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.Florilegium [.{Ch A} {Yes} ]
[.{Ch B} {No} ] ] 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


You need to load the tikz-qtree package if you'd like to use macros from it:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% each tikzpicture is placed on a new page

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=left,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.Florilegium [.{Ch A} {Yes} ]
[.{Ch B} {No} ] ] 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


